# How to properly use JQuery hasData()?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I've got a basic front-end-only web app where a button gets clicked, a GET Request is sent to the Foursquare API, and then AJAX stores some of the request's response data into a div as follows:

```
checkinsCount[i] = data.response.venues[i].stats.checkinsCount;
$("#fs_results").data("checkinsCount", checkinsCount);
d = $("#fs_results").data("checkinsCount");
console.log(d);
```

I then have a checkbox, where I want to display the data in a div when the checkbox is clicked, but ONLY after verifying that the data exists already.

So I'm trying to use jQuery's .hasData() to check this:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function () {
if($.hasData($('#fs_results'))){
  $("#fs_results").toggle(this.checked);
} else{
  alert("false");
  $('#checkbox1').attr('checked', false);

}
});
```

But right now, I'm just getting the false alert repeatedly, even when I have verified the data is present. I'm lost as this is my first time using jQuery/AJAX...any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hasData operates on a single element i believe (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.hasData/)), you are passing in a query result.

Thus replacing

`if($.hasData($('#fs_results'))){`

with

`if($.hasData($('#fs_results')[0])){`

should solve the problem. Separately, you should be using `prop()` and not `attr()` on the checkbox.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! What's the exact difference between prop() and attr()?

Comment: attr refers to the attribute that was set when the HTML was rendered, so the actual text of the tag. prop is the dynamic value of the property based on user or programmatic changes. strictly speaking, attr should not change after the element is rendered. jQuery changed how they handle this back in version 1.4 and broke a lot of websites, so better to stick with prop